# Unable to pass a string from Android-client to WCF-service

Tags: c#, android, wpf, web-services, wcf

I need to transfer data (string) from the Android-client to WCF-service. But I can not do it - Android-client accesses the service method, but the string is not passed, it is always empty. But PC has access to the file to record.

I have a WCF-service that enables communication with the Android-application. I placed the service in IIS, and work with the Android emulator in Android Studio. Hosted WCF-Service has been posted is correct, at least transmits the data to the Android-application is good

The Android-app transfer is as follows:

```
private class ConWCF extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{protected String doInBackground(Void... params){ 
InputStream inputStream = null;
String result = "";
try {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.94:8080/Test.svc/Login");
    String json = "";
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("firstname", "Alex");
        jsonObject.put("secondName", "Petrov");
        jsonObject.put("street", "Arbat");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    json = jsonObject.toString();
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
    httpPost.setEntity(se);
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
    inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
    if(inputStream != null)
        result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
    else
        result = "Did not work!";
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
return result;}}
```

Wcf-service get json-lines by using the following code:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Login",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
      )]
    void Login(String str);

public void Login(String str){
    var filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myFile.txt"];
    StreamWriter file;
    file = File.AppendText(filePath + "/myFile.txt");
    if (str == null)
    {
        file.WriteLine("пусто");
    }
    else
    {
        file.WriteLine(str);
    }
    file.WriteLine(str);
    file.Close();
}
```

In the Web.config I also set the path to the file that I want to record.

```
<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" /><add key="myFile.txt" value="C:\Papka" />
```

When I am checking records without Android-application using WPF-client - record runs correctly. Android-clien has all manifests for permission to work with internet

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question but why not use ASP.NET Web API instead?

Comment: @CliveSeebregts, client decided to use wcf-service for this